# Defining greater than for a iPhone 6 screen size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am using code which shows a certain xib file depending on the device, at the moment 3 xibs, one for iPhone4, one for iPhone5 and one for iPad.

Since iOS8 / iPhone 6, the app does not work on anything higher than the 5s due to the fact the xib does not know what to load;

```
- (IBAction)btnTapForStart:(id)sender {

    fromOtherClass=YES;

    if([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height == 568)
    {
        PlayMusicViewController *pmvc = [[PlayMusicViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"XibForIPhone5" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:pmvc animated:YES];

    }
    else
    {
        PlayMusicViewController *pmvc = [[PlayMusicViewController alloc]init];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:pmvc animated:YES];
    }

    [appObject.audioPlayer stop];
}
```

If I change the value of 568 to higher it will work, but is there a way to combine it, for example, height is 568 OR iPhone6 size OR iPhone 6 plus size etc?

Comment: Why do you have multiple xibs? Just use one for all devices (maybe a 2nd for iPad). Use auto layout and constraints to get everything sized and positioned properly.

Comment: I did not write the code originally, and just wish to fix it so it works for those who have the app and use an iPhone 6/6 Plus, I can worry about refining the code afterwards, but this is a more urgent fix...

Thanks to whoever marked this answer down also...

Comment: What's your question then? Do you want to use the iPhone 5 xib for the iPhone 6 or do you have another xib specific to the iPhone 6?

Comment: Indeed, I would just like to (temporarily) use the iPhone 5 xib if user has a 6 or 6 plus.

Comment: If your app isn't (for now anyway) going to natively support the iPhone 6 then there is nothing to do. Be sure you don't add any iPhone 6 launch images or the new iOS 8 "Launch Screen file" and your app will think it is running on an iPhone 5 (size-wise) when running on the iPhone 6 or 6+. You don't need any extra code.

Comment: It doesn't work on the iPhone 6, I already tried downloading it from the store...

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: It does not load the view... Like I already said in my first post, as it is looking for a device with a 568 height, and because the iPhone6 is larger, then it does not load...Hence my original question.

Comment: But existing apps not updated specifically for the iPhone 6 will return 568 as the screen height, even on an iPhone 6. Unless your app is landscape then it will report 320 as the height. This is an iOS 8 change.

Comment: Yeah, a lot of the other apps are fine but yes this app is a landscape app which could indeed by why the issue occurs...

Comment: Then simply change the code to see if the height or the width is 568 and you are done.

Comment: It already does that... It works on iPhone 5, I just need to figure how to make it look for the 6/6 plus height also to use the same xib

Answer (score 1):

You probably should use auto-layout like Maddy says, but if you want to have code that works for specific devices, then you might want to implement this utility method. Then you can create as many xibs as you want and target them to specific devices. e.g.

```
if ([[Utilities deviceType] isEqualToString:@"iPhone Retina4"] || [[Utilities deviceType] isEqualToString:@"iPhone Retina35"] ) {
   -- do something specific for these phones
}
```

I put this method in a Utilities class.

```
+ (NSString *)deviceType {
    NSString *device = nil;
    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    CGFloat deviceScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        device = @"iPhone Classic"; // Just in case it doesn't make it through the conditionals
        // Classic has a resolution of 480 × 320
        if( (screenSize.height == 480 || screenSize.width == 480) && deviceScale == 1.0f ) {
            device = @"iPhone Classic";
        // Retina has a resolution of 960 × 640
        } else if( (screenSize.height == 480 || screenSize.width == 480) && deviceScale == 2.0f ) {
            device = @"iPhone Retina35";
        // Retina 4" has a resolution of 1136 x 640
        } else if (screenSize.height == 568 || screenSize.width == 568 ) {
            device = @"iPhone Retina4";
        // iPhone 6 has a resolution of 1334 by 750
        } else if (screenSize.height == 667 || screenSize.width == 667 ) {
            device = @"iPhone 6";
        // iPhone 6 Plus has an actual size of 2208 × 1242 and resolution of 1920 by 1080
        // Reported size is 736 x 414
        } else if (screenSize.height == 736 || screenSize.width == 736 ) {
            device = @"iPhone 6 Plus";
        }

    } else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        device = @"iPad Classic"; // Just in case it doesn't make it through the conditionals
        if(deviceScale == 1.0f) {
            device = @"iPad Classic";
        } else if (deviceScale == 2.0f) {
            device = @"iPad Retina";
        }
    }
    //NSLog(@"The device is %@ scale is %f and the height is %f and width is %f", device, deviceScale, screenSize.height, screenSize.width);

    return device;
}
```

Comment: Why would you use strings here? An enum would do.

Comment: @StilesCrisis, I don’t have formal language training so there are large holes in my knowledge base. My knowledge of enums and how to use them is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research on enums and they are nice. They make the code a bit more readable, but mostly they allow the compiler to help you type and catch errors. Xcode will autocomplete your deviceType for you and will give you the error: **Use of undeclared identifier** if you try to use a value that isn’t defined. Here’s the code rewritten as an enum. I prefixed  the values with LF but you should use whatever is appropriate for your project.

This is in my header file

```
// Devices as of Fall 2014
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, LFdeviceType) {
    LFDeviceTypePhoneClassic,
    LFDeviceTypePhoneRetina3_5,
    LFDeviceTypePhoneRetina4,
    LFDeviceTypePhone6,
    LFDeviceTypePhone6Plus,
    LFDeviceTypePadClassic,
    LFDeviceTypePadRetina,
};
```

And this is in my .m file.

```
m+ (NSInteger)deviceType {
    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    CGFloat deviceScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    LFdeviceType device = LFDeviceTypePhoneClassic;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        device = LFDeviceTypePhoneClassic; // Just in case it doesn't make it through the conditionals
        // Classic has a resolution of 480 × 320
        if( (screenSize.height == 480 || screenSize.width == 480) && deviceScale == 1.0f ) {
            device = LFDeviceTypePhoneClassic;
        // Retina has a resolution of 960 × 640
        } else if( (screenSize.height == 480 || screenSize.width == 480) && deviceScale == 2.0f ) {
            device = LFDeviceTypePhoneRetina3_5;
        // Retina 4" has a resolution of 1136 x 640
        } else if (screenSize.height == 568 || screenSize.width == 568 ) {
            device = LFDeviceTypePhoneRetina4;
        // iPhone 6 has a resolution of 1334 by 750
        } else if (screenSize.height == 667 || screenSize.width == 667 ) {
            device = LFDeviceTypePhone6;
        // iPhone 6 Plus has an actual size of 2208 × 1242 and resolution of 1920 by 1080
        // Reported size is 736 x 414
        } else if (screenSize.height == 736 || screenSize.width == 736 ) {
            device = LFDeviceTypePhone6Plus;
        }

    } else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        device = LFDeviceTypePadClassic; // Just in case it doesn't make it through the conditionals
        if(deviceScale == 1.0f) {
            device = LFDeviceTypePadClassic;
        } else if (deviceScale == 2.0f) {
            device = LFDeviceTypePadRetina;
        }
    }
    //NSLog(@"The device is %@ scale is %f and the height is %f and width is %f", device, deviceScale, screenSize.height, screenSize.width);

    return device;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
if ( (   [Utilities deviceType] == LFDeviceTypePhoneClassic 
      || [Utilities deviceType] == LFDeviceTypePhoneRetina3_5) &&
        numberOfFoilsOnScreen > 7 ) {
        numberOfFoilsOnScreen = 7;
}
```